How exactly does tensorflow perform mini-batch gradient descent?
I am unable to achieve  good results unless I choose a batch size of 1. By good, I mean error decreases significantly through the epochs. When I do a full batch of 30 the results are poor, error behaves erratically decreasing only slightly and then learning nothing, or increasing. However, tensorflow gets good results for any batch_size with these same settings.
My question is, what is wrong with my gradient descent method?
In addition, How is tensorflow different? How do the gradients remain so stable through the epochs without, apparently, scaling or clipping them with default SGD settings?
#%%
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
p = 10
N = 30
w = np.random.uniform(-1,1, (p,1))
X = np.random.normal(0,1, (N,p))
y = np.matmul(X,w) + np.random.normal(0,1,(N,1))
#%%

class layer:
    def __init__(self, out_dim, input=False, in_dim=None):
        self.out_dim = out_dim 
        if not input:
            self.weights = np.random.normal(0,1.0/out_dim,(out_dim, in_dim)) 
            self.input_bit = 0
        else:
            self.input_bit = 1 
        
    def compute_self(self, z):
        if self.input_bit==0:
            self.z = np.matmul(self.weights,z) 
        else:
            self.z = z 
        return np.reshape(self.z, (-1,1))
    
class network:
    def __init__(self):
        self.layers = [] 
    
    def add_layer(self, layer):
        self.layers.append(layer)
        
    def compute_net_iter(self, x, L):
        if L==(len(self.layers)-1):
            return np.squeeze(self.layers[len(self.layers)-1].compute_self(self.layers[L-1].z))
        if L==0:
            self.layers[0].compute_self(x)
            return self.compute_net_iter(self.layers[0].z, L+1)
        else:
            self.layers[L].compute_self(self.layers[L-1].z)
            return self.compute_net_iter(self.layers[L].z, L+1)
        
    def compute_output(self,X):
        y = [] 
        
        for i in range(X.shape[0]):
            y.append(self.compute_net_iter(X[i,:], 0))
        return np.reshape(np.array(y), (-1,1))
    
    def mse(self, yhat, y):
        return np.mean(np.power(yhat - y,2))
    
    def grad_E(self, yhat, y):
        return np.reshape(np.sum(yhat - y), (-1, 1))
    
    def batch_data(self, X,y, size):
        nrows = X.shape[0]
        rand_rows = np.random.permutation(range(nrows))
        batches = int(nrows/size)
        rem = nrows%size 
        if rem:
            batches += 1
        b = 0 
        Xbatches = {}
        ybatches = {} 
        c = 0 

        while b < nrows:
            if b+size>nrows:
                e = nrows-b 
            else:
                e = size 
            
            r = rand_rows[b:(b+e)]
            Xbatches[c] = X[r,:]

            ybatches[c] = y[r,:]
            b+=size  
            c+=1
        return Xbatches, ybatches 


    def update(self, X,y, epochs=10, batch_size=32, lr=.01):
        deltas = {} 
        for i in range(1,len(self.layers)):
            deltas[i] = 0  
        
        for e in range(epochs):
            Xbatches, ybatches = self.batch_data(X,y, batch_size)
            batches = len(ybatches)
            for b in range(batches):
                yhat = self.compute_output(Xbatches[b])
                grad_E = self.grad_E(yhat, ybatches[b])/len(yhat)
                z = np.reshape(self.layers[-2].z, (-1,1))
                grad_W = np.matmul(grad_E, z.T)
                deltas[len(self.layers)-1] = grad_W
                for L in reversed(range(1, len(self.layers)-1)):
                    grad_E = np.matmul(self.layers[L+1].weights.T, grad_E)
                    z = np.reshape(self.layers[L-1].z, (-1,1))
                    grad_W = np.matmul(grad_E, z.T)
                    deltas[L] = grad_W
                for L in range(1,len(self.layers)):
                    self.layers[L].weights = self.layers[L].weights - (lr*deltas[L]) 
            yhat = self.compute_output(X)
            err = self.mse(yhat, y)
            print(err)
    
layer0 = layer(X.shape[1], input=True)  
layer1 = layer(10, in_dim=layer0.out_dim)  
layer2 = layer(1, in_dim=layer1.out_dim)

net = network()
net.add_layer(layer0)
net.add_layer(layer1)
net.add_layer(layer2)

net.update(X,y, epochs=30, batch_size=30, lr=.01)
yhat = net.compute_output(X)
plt.plot(yhat)
plt.plot(y)
plt.show()

# %%



One step better than before. Trying to do matrix algebra for update was not working for me. I am going to start working on how to get that to work in one step instead of iterating but until then doing it by iterating over rows has led to improvement.
#%%
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
p = 10
N = 30
w = np.random.uniform(-1,1, (p,1))
X = np.random.normal(0,1, (N,p))
y = np.matmul(X,w) + np.random.normal(0,1,(N,1))
#%%

class layer:
    def __init__(self, out_dim, input=False, output=False, in_dim=None):
        self.out_dim = out_dim 
        self.input_bit=False
        self.output_bit=False  
        if not input and not output:
            self.weights = np.random.normal(0, .5,(out_dim, in_dim)) 
            self.input_bit = 0
        elif output:
            self.weights = np.random.normal(0, .5,(out_dim, in_dim)) 
            self.output_bit = 1
        else:
            self.weights = None 
            self.input_bit = 1 
        
    def compute_self(self, z):
        if self.input_bit==0:
            self.z = np.matmul(self.weights,z) 
        else:
            self.z = z 
        return np.reshape(self.z, (-1,1))
    
    def grad_E_w(self, z_input, yhat=None, y=None, output_delta=None, Output_Weights=None):
        if (self.output_bit==True) and (y is not None) and (yhat is not None):
            self.delta_E = self.grad_E_z(yhat, y)
            del_W = self.delta_E * z_input.T 
            del_Wl1 = np.abs(del_W) 
            del_W[del_Wl1<1e-7] = 0 
            return del_W
        elif (not self.input_bit) and (output_delta is not None) and (Output_Weights is not None):
            self.delta_E = Output_Weights.T*output_delta 
            del_W = self.delta_E * z_input.T 
            del_Wl1 = np.abs(del_W) 
            del_W[del_Wl1<1e-7] = 0 
            return del_W
        else:
            raise Exception('Invalid input in grad_E_w. Called gradient on input layer?')

    def grad_E_z(self, yhat, y):
        return np.reshape(np.sum(yhat - y), (-1, 1))
    
class network:
    def __init__(self):

        self.layers = [] 
    
    def add_layer(self, layer):
        self.layers.append(layer)
        
    def compute_net_iter(self, x, L):
        if L==(len(self.layers)-1):
            return np.squeeze(self.layers[len(self.layers)-1].compute_self(self.layers[L-1].z))
        if L==0:
            self.layers[0].compute_self(x)
            return self.compute_net_iter(self.layers[0].z, L+1)
        else:
            self.layers[L].compute_self(self.layers[L-1].z)
            return self.compute_net_iter(self.layers[L].z, L+1)
        
    def compute_output(self,X):
        y = [] 
        for i in range(X.shape[0]):
            y.append(self.compute_net_iter(X[i,:], 0))
        return np.reshape(np.array(y), (-1,1))
    
    def mse(self, yhat, y):
        return np.mean(np.power(yhat - y,2))
    
    def batch_data(self, X,y, size):
        nrows = X.shape[0]
        rand_rows = np.random.permutation(range(nrows))
        batches = int(nrows/size)
        rem = nrows%size 
        if rem:
            batches += 1
        b = 0 
        Xbatches = {}
        ybatches = {} 
        c = 0 
        while b < nrows:
            if b+size>nrows:
                e = nrows-b 
            else:
                e = size 
            r = rand_rows[b:(b+e)]
            Xbatches[c] = X[r,:]

            ybatches[c] = y[r,:]
            b+=size  
            c+=1
        return Xbatches, ybatches 
    
    def weight_gradient(self, X,y):
        epsilon = 1e-8
        grad = [] 
        for L in reversed(range(1, len(self.layers))):
            g = [] 
            for i in range(self.layers[L].weights.shape[0]):
                for j in range(self.layers[L].weights.shape[1]):
                    self.layers[L].weights[i, j] += epsilon 
                    yup = self.compute_output(X).sum().squeeze()
                    self.layers[L].weights[i, j] -= epsilon 
                    ydown = self.compute_output(X).sum().squeeze() 
                    g.append((yup - ydown)/(2*epsilon))
            grad.append(np.array(g))
        return grad 
    
    def check_gradient(self, X, y):
        yhat = self.compute_output(X) 
        old_cost = self.mse(yhat, y)
        print("current old_cost {}".format(old_cost))
        
        del_dict = {}
        for i in reversed(range(1, len(self.layers))):
            z_input = np.reshape(self.layers[i-1].z, (-1,1))
            if self.layers[i].output_bit==True:
                gw = self.layers[i].grad_E_w(z_input, yhat, y)
            else:
                deltas = self.layers[i+1].delta_E
                W = self.layers[i+1].weights
                gw = self.layers[i].grad_E_w(z_input, output_delta=deltas, Output_Weights=W)
            del_dict[i] = [] 
            del_dict[i].append(gw)

        delta = -1e-4
        for i in reversed(range(1, len(self.layers))):
            d = del_dict[i][0]
            for k in range(self.layers[i].weights.shape[0]):
                for j in range(self.layers[i].weights.shape[1]):
                    self.layers[i].weights[k,j] += delta
                    yhat = self.compute_output(X)
                    cost = self.mse(yhat, y)  
                    print('diff {}'.format(cost - (old_cost + d[k,j]*delta)))

    def update(self, X,y, epochs=10, batch_size=32, lr=.01):
        Xbatches, ybatches = self.batch_data(X,y, batch_size)
        batches = len(ybatches)
        for e in range(epochs+1):
            for b in range(batches):
                store_grads = {}
                M = len(ybatches[b]) 
                for L in reversed(range(1,len(self.layers))):
                    gradF = np.zeros(self.layers[L].weights.shape)
                    store_grads[L] = [] 
                    for k in range(ybatches[b].shape[0]):
                        xb = np.reshape(Xbatches[b][k,:], (1,-1))
                        yb = np.reshape(ybatches[b][k,:], (1,1))
                        yhat = self.compute_output(xb)
                        z_input = np.reshape(self.layers[L-1].z, (-1,1))
                        if self.layers[L].output_bit:
                            gradF += self.layers[L].grad_E_w(z_input, yhat, yb)
                        else:
                            deltas = self.layers[L+1].delta_E
                            W = self.layers[L+1].weights
                            gradF += self.layers[L].grad_E_w(z_input, output_delta=deltas, Output_Weights=W)
                    store_grads[L] = lr*gradF/M
                for L in range(1, len(self.layers)):
                    self.layers[L].weights -= store_grads[L]
            yhat = self.compute_output(X)
            print('error {}'.format(self.mse(yhat, y)))

